# how using condition trying to catch data a column and then store data of anather column to a variable

Tags: python

```
>   Var     imp
77  V78     0.000000
80  V81     0.000000
47  V48     0.000000
49  V50     0.000000
83  V84     0.000000
52  V53     0.000000
10  V11     0.000000
20  V21     0.000000
55  V56     0.000000
62  V63     0.000000
```

I am trying to get all the `Var` in a variable where `imp` is 0. I am not able to do it. giving me `keyerror 'Var11'`

```
ar=np.array(ar)
for i in range(len(sd['imp'])):
    if sd['imp'][i]==0:
        ar=sd[sd['Var'][i]]
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) for select column `var` with [`values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.values.html) for `numpy array`:

```
arr = sd.loc[sd['imp'] == 0, 'Var'].values
print (arr)
['V78' 'V81' 'V48' 'V50' 'V84' 'V53' 'V11' 'V21' 'V56' 'V63']
```

Alternative with [`query`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) for filtering:

```
arr = sd.query('imp == 0')['Var'].values
```

Detail:

```
print (sd.loc[sd['imp'] == 0, 'Var'])
77    V78
80    V81
47    V48
49    V50
83    V84
52    V53
10    V11
20    V21
55    V56
62    V63
Name: Var, dtype: object
```